# Is there the event in Ext.grid.Panel that fires when the data and rows have been reloaded and rendered

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

The main point of the question: I need the event that fires when the new rows have been rendered and the selection has been restored.
I refresh my grid by calling store.load method. I have a handler for store.load event. It fires when data have been loaded, but before new rows rendering.
I tried afterrender, viewready, selectionchange both in Ext.grid.Panel and Ext.view.Table (the view of the gird), but these events don't fire after every store.load event.
I need this event to work with the restored selection and perform some operations.

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling the load call doRefresh() it will fire beforechange event and change events on the paging toolbar then handle those things in those events do what ever you want todo

Comment: Excuse me, but I do not see any member named doRefresh neither in Grid nor Store (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html).

Comment: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?184111-How-to-override-refresh-button-of-pagingtoolbar   check this

Comment: I do not use and I am not going to use paging toolbar. I use infinite scroll.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
grid.getView().refresh();
```

method after store load. It will refresh grid view content.